# Method name changed from Obj C to swift

Tags: swift

It's not a big problem, but I was a bit confused when I faced it for the first time.
This was the original declaration for an Obj C delegate method:

```
- (void)serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort
```

And when I translated it in swift it became:

```
func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort)
```

But later Xcode showed an error and suggested me to change the name, because it was deprecated, in this one:

```
func serialPortWasRemoved(fromSystem serialPort: ORSSerialPort)
```

Why did they change this delegate name so many times? Can you tell me why? Thank you! ~

Comment: They changed function syntaxes in Swift 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that, in large part, is what Swift 3 *is*. The Objective-C APIs are "renamified" to make their names terser and more Swift-like.

To learn more, read [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) and the other two documents to which it links.

Comment: See also my brief discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_methods

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @matt. The Objective-C APIs are "renamified" to make their names terser and more Swift-like

```
// Objective-c SampleObC.h
@interface SampleObC : NSObject
 +(void)getSampleName;
 +(void)setSampleName;
}

// Swift 
class SampleSwift {
  // Sample Class Name is ignored.
  SampleObC.getName()
  SampleObC.setName()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**